# How to expand/resize image when click on thumbnail

Tags: flutter

I have a structure like in WhatsApp. When i click on thumbnail i would like to expand/resize in screen. How can i do that?

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        // code?
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 150.0,
        height: 150.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/person.png'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a [`Hero`](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations) but I don't use WhatsApp so without a screenshot it's hard to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On clicking the image display a dialogBox with only Image as its child, and use Hero widget animation.